# Static file "debug_toolbar/css/print.css" does not exist when starting Kiwi Tcms

Tags: django, python-3.x, kiwi-tcms

I'm trying to run Kiwi TCMS on my pc, windows 10, and getting error :
Exception at /accounts/login/
Static file "debug_toolbar/css/print.css" does not exist and will cause 404 errors!
I don't know what's wrong, already searched and tried the solutions from stackoverflow (that I found relevant) but nothing worked for me.

There one thing I want to share, that kereberos was making problems in windows so I installed winkerberos. I did this by changing install_requires of [tcms-api](https://github.com/kiwitcms/tcms-api) , kerberos to winkerberos. It was installed, and everything else was too. Does this make any problem?
Do I have to change or configure something for winkerberos on behalf of kerberos?

Screenshots are attached.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdByo.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0EDf.png)

Answer (score 2):

The bug you hit has to do with the (now rectified, former) behavior of the `tcms.tests.storage.RaiseWhenFileNotFound` storage class.

This storage class is used during testing and development (set in `tcms/settings/devel.py`) to discover missing static files so that KiwiTCMS developers can get an early warning if they mess something up.

At the time you encountered the bug, this storage class wasn't working well on Windows because it didn't take into consideration when discovering files that the path separator on Windows is `\\`.

So, while it discovered the static files on Windows alright, it could never find a match for them against what was specified in the Django templates — the static files in the templates were specified with the familiar `/` as path separators.

But that was then.

It's a different story now. [The aforementioned storage class has been rewritten to work well on Windows](https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/pull/1334), and so you should not be hitting this bug any longer.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install -r requirements/devel.txt`  b/c debug-toolbar is only enabled in devel mode

Comment: Thanks for your time,I did this already when installing Kiwi, and all the requirements are satisfied, tried again just right now.

Comment: Added some more information in question description, please have a look.