# Kiwi Tcms Windows Installation and Configuration without docker

Tags: windows, configuration, installation, kiwi-tcms

I want to run Kiwi tcms on my windows, but i'm unable. 
I've followed instructions on [this](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html) that is for linux based, but i managed to run these on my windows, except `npm install patternfly` as I can't find patterfly, but installed npm only.
There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297178/static-file-debug-toolbar-css-print-css-does-not-exist-when-starting-kiwi-tcms) I've asked where I'm stuck, so If I did anything wrong, please guide me so I can do it from the start.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a guide how to deploy Django applications on Windows. We don't really use Windows and deploying from something else than a Docker container isn't really supported so you need to know what you are doing. If this is new to you you'd better stick to using docker-compose!